# How do video editing programs process large files?

Tags: video, video-editing

Imagine a video is 4 seconds long at 4k 25fps. An editing tool would process the compressed video file to raw pixels and frames i assume, because editing the compressed one is very complicated. But in that case, the memory would be so large right?

- 4k is 8294400 pixels
- Each pixel would take 4 bytes for rgba, so 8294400 * 4 = 33177600 bytes
- 33177600 * 24 frames is 796262400 bytes(759 megabytes)
  759 MB for just one second is too much right? Then how do video editors handle them efficiently?

Comment: What makes you think they need to handle 25 frames at a time? Why not 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few points to consider:

- when dealing with huge files video editors use so named proxies, low res files which are used for editing and only on final rendering are used full res files.
- in video are used different chroma subsampling formats (output) like 4:4:4, 4:2:2, 4:2:0 which decrease the amount of bits per pixel. Only RAW videos (input) use more bits per pixel and in this case they can be 10 or 12 bits.
- in video are used different codecs to shrink the file size
- as mentioned in comment the final render do not need to be with 24/25/30 FPS, can be only few frames per second (the speed of rendering, not the speed of video).
- Video formats usually have full information only for so named key frames. Other frames are just difference between key frame and iframes. (this usually is a part of the codec definition)
- do not forget the effects, LUN's, etc which make things worst (in sense of consumed CPU)
- usually video editors take advantage of multicore configurations.
- final rendering can be done on servers (server farms) with many processors, cores and RAM

Comment: Video also uses 'difference' frames, which will also keep data throughput down.

Comment: @Tetsujin, very good point. Will add it

Comment: Can final rendering use gpu?

Comment: That's a completely different question & actually one where the answer is unimportant to quality or resource usage, only to speed.